# Implement "pagename.html#id_of_section" similar functionality in php

Tags: php, html

I am currently working on a php project in which i needed to implement a page redirection.In HTML the page redirection

`<a href=abc.html#section>Pagename<a/>`

works proper to get me to any section of the page. But in php i tried to implement the same with tag and include method which gives me error.the code i tried is

`if(?tag==tagname)
include('pagename.php#section');`

How can i redirect visitor to some other page on some section which is in middle of the page?? implementing **abc.html#section** in php. Please give your guidance. Thanx in advance.

The structure is

```
<html>
<body>
<header>

<Navigation menu>
<a href="?tag=home"><span>Home</span></a>
</end Navigation menu>

<php> 
if(?tag==home)
include(home.php);
</end php>

<footer>
</end body>
</end html>
```

This works fine but it will always open new page from the top. I needed to take users to home.php#section. Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

use $_GET to access query-paramters.
e.g.:

index.php?foo=bar&some=thing

$_GET['foo']; //contains bar

$_GET['some']; // contains thing

```
<html>
<body>
<header>

<Navigation menu>
<a href="?tag=home"><span>Home</span></a>
</end Navigation menu>

<?php
if(isset($_GET) && $_GET['tag'] && $_GET['tag'] == 'home') {
       include(home.php);
}
?>

<footer>
</end body>
</end html>
```

Comment: thanks for answering @Henry but the page errors up saying cannot modify header. What to do next??

Comment: see my edit. header() must be called before any output (whitespaces, html) is sent.

Comment: I have used the code to include pages between header navigation and footer, like below <header><navigation bar> <index,service,about us pages to included as per tag names> <footer>. it is somewhat same as your not working scenario but it works successfully if i only include .php pages without #section. So could there be nay other solution??